# Transfer pivot table with double index (group: country; group: code) and double rows (group: country; group: code) to a pandas table with four rows?

Tags: python, pandas

I try to load a pivot table with two index columns and two rows heading to a pandas that holds for rows ?

```
    raw_data = pd.read_csv(file_path, header=[0,1], index_col=[0,1], low_memory=False)

    print(f"Data melting\n.")

    data_reset = raw_data.reset_index()

    # Melting data
    melted_data = pd.melt(data_reset, id_vars=[('Geo', ''), ('Code', '')])

    melted_data['geo_2'], melted_data['code_2'] = zip(*melted_data['variable'])

    final_data = melted_data.rename(columns={
        ('Geo', ''): 'geo_1',
        ('Code',''): 'code_1',
        'value': 'value'
    })

    final_data = final_data[['geo_1', 'geo_2', 'code_1', 'code_2', 'value']]

    print(final_data.head())
```

print final_data.head() shows:

```
Geo                 ABW                                          ...       ZWE
Code                      A01       A02       A03         B   C10-C12  ...       P85         Q       R_S         T         U
Geo       Code                                                       ...
ABW       A01      0.000192  0.000095  0.000153  0.001616  0.709610  ...  0.002305  0.004002  0.002029  0.013534  0.012778
          A02      0.000249  0.000052  0.000084  0.000605  0.002513  ...  0.000461  0.000801  0.000406  0.008072  0.008647
          A03      0.000192  0.000021  0.000033  0.000016  0.028014  ...  0.001869  0.003243  0.001645  0.005666  0.004353
          B        0.007889  0.001219  0.001965  0.467401  0.071695  ...  0.002241  0.003889  0.001972  0.013528  0.012716
          C10-C12  0.118333  0.003355  0.005409  0.003407  1.347371  ...  0.002242  0.003892  0.001974  0.015993  0.015432
```

I try to read a large CSV with two index columns and two heading rows pivot table where index and heading are the same geo and code and transfer it two a four row  array / df : code, code, row, row = value. The idea is to transfer a 100 000 x 100 000 CSV to SQL table that contains only five rows.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hello, your wording is difficult to understand. Additionally, it has been brought to your attention that SO questions require [mre] whenever possible. As you are not providing input data. Please read [ask], take the quick [tour]. If this is a question about reading a csv, how about providing part of the upper portion of the csv, and adding tag read_csv for findability?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using "from itertools import product"

Reading the CSV into pandas :     raw_data = pd.read_csv(file_path, header=[0,1], index_col=[0,1], low_memory=False)

and thereafter

```
for (row_heading_1, row_heading_2), (col_heading_1, col_heading_2) in product(raw_data.index, raw_data.columns):
        try:
            selected_data = raw_data.loc[(row_heading_1, row_heading_2), (col_heading_1, col_heading_2)]
            selected_data_value = selected_data.values[0] if isinstance(selected_data, pd.Series) and selected_data.size == 1 else selected_data
        
            record = {
                "geo_1": row_heading_1,
                "geo_2": col_heading_1,
                "code_1": row_heading_2,
                "code_2": col_heading_2,
                "value": selected_data_value
            }
        
            record_size = get_size(record)
        
            if current_size + record_size > 100 * 1024 * 1024:  # 100MB limit
                # Insert current chunk
                with engine.connect() as connection:
                    try:
                        result = connection.execute(insert(IOTable), values_to_insert)
                        print(f"Inserted {result.rowcount} rows.")
                        connection.commit()
                    except Exception as e:
                        print(f"Error: {str(e)}")
            
                # Reset for the next chunk
                values_to_insert = []
                current_size = 0
```

Comment: Good that you found what you need. For next times: taking care to formulate your answer clearly and provide initial data, should help getting answers from people here.